# Computation of norm of $\theta^2-4$, where $\theta=\zeta_p+\zeta_p^{-1}$ and $\zeta_p$ is a primitive $p-th$ root of unity.

Tags: number-theory

I have been stuck on this for a while now. Here is what I have so far.

For a general $m\ge 3$, I have proved the following:
(i) $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ is a degree 2 extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ with the minimal polynomial $X^2-\theta X+1$.
(ii) Gal($\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}(\theta))=\{1,\sigma\}$, where $\sigma:\zeta_m\to \zeta_m^{-1}$.
(iii) $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\theta)}=\mathbb{R}\cap \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_m]=\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$.
The last think I need to prove to complete the problem is to prove that when $m$ is an odd prime $p$, then $N_{\mathbb{Q}(\theta)/\mathbb{Q}}(\theta^2-4)=\pm p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to get the sign of the norm (since the answer by peter a g tells us the rest). Let $m$ be an odd prime. Put $K=\mathbb Q(\theta)$. We have
$$
\operatorname{N}_{K/\mathbb Q} = \prod_\sigma \left( \sigma(\theta)^2 - 4 \right) = \prod_\sigma \left( \sigma(\theta) -2 \right)\left( \sigma(\theta) +2 \right) = P(2)P(-2)
$$
where $P$ is the minimal polynomial of $\theta$. Since all zeros of $P$ are of the form $2 \cos(2 \pi k / m)$, the zeros $x$ of $P$ must satisfy $-2 < x < 2$, and hence the sign of $P(2)P(-2)$ must be odd when the degree of $P$ is odd, and even otherwise. In other words, the sign equals $(-1)^{(m-1)/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $L= \mathbb Q(\zeta)$, and $K= \mathbb Q(\theta)$  (the maximal real subfield of $L$.)

Hint: On the one hand, $$N_L(\theta^2-4)=\large[N_K(\theta^2-4) \large]^2 .$$

On the other, $\theta^2-4 = (\zeta -\zeta^{-1})^2$,
so that  $$N_L(\theta^2-4) = \large[N_L(\zeta-\zeta^{-1})\large]^2.$$

Calculate the norm on the RHS.

*Edit* The point is that $$x^{p-1}+\cdots +1 = {x^p -1 \over x-1} = \prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x-z^k),$$
where $z$ is a $p$th primitive root of unity (e.g., $z= \zeta^{\pm 2}$, here). Therefore $p = \prod_{k=1}^{p-1} (1-z^k)$.

Comment: So the problem boils down to calculating $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(\zeta_p\pm 1)$. Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Namely, if so, you probably should have in your notes $p= N_{L/\mathbb Q} (1-\zeta_p)$.

Comment: No. This is not part of any assignment, homework or otherwise. I am trying to learn more about cyclotomic fields for a research paper of mine.

Comment: OK, hold on, then.

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Yes absolutely. I feel silly for even asking this. Thank you and apologies both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Norm of $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)/\mathbb{Q}$: $$\prod_{\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{Q(\theta) / \mathbb{Q}})} \sigma(\theta^2-4) = \prod_{\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{Q(\theta) / \mathbb{Q}})} (\sigma(\theta)^2-4)$$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_of_2cos(2pi/n)
Hence,

for $1 \leq i \leq \frac{p-1}{2}$
$\sigma_i(\zeta_p+\zeta_p^{-1}) = \zeta_p^i+\zeta_p^{-i}$.

Hence
Norm of $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)/\mathbb{Q}$: $$\prod_{\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{Q(\theta) / \mathbb{Q}})} (\sigma(\theta)^2-4) = \prod_{1 \leq i \leq \frac{p-1}{2}} ((\zeta_p^i+\zeta_p^{-i})^2-4)$$ $$= 2^{p-1} \times (-1)^{(p-1)/2} \times \prod_{1 \leq i \leq \frac{p-1}{2}} (1-cos^2(2 \pi i/p))$$ $$= 2^{p-1} \times (-1)^{(p-1)/2} \times \prod_{1 \leq i \leq \frac{p-1}{2}} sin^2(2 \pi i/p)$$

Let $p=3$, then we get $$ = 2^2 \times (-1) \times sin^2(2\pi/3) = -3$$.

Use https://www.jstor.org/stable/3219105 to find $$\prod_{1 \leq i \leq \frac{p-1}{2}} sin^2(2 \pi i/p) = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} \times S_p(0)/coef \ of \ x^{(p-1)/2} \ in \ S_p(x)$$
where $S_p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $sin(2\pi/p)$ given in https://www.jstor.org/stable/3219105

Here coefficient of $x^{(p-1)/2}$ in $S_p(x)$ is sum of odd binomial coefficients times $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$:
Using https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Odd_Index_Binomial_Coefficients
This value is $(-1)^{(p-1)/2} \times 2^{p-1}$. Also $S_p(0) = p$.

Hence
$$\prod_{1 \leq i \leq \frac{p-1}{2}} sin^2(2 \pi i/p) = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} \times S_p(0)/coef \ of \ x^{(p-1)/2} \ in \ S_p(x) = p/2^{p-1}$$

Hence we have the result that Norm of $\theta^2-4$ is $$(-1)^{(p-1)/2} p$$.

Comment: As a sanity check, try $p=3$. Then $\theta =-1$, and the norm equals $-3$.

Comment: The error is in last step. Removed it. Now its consistent with $p=3$ case.

Comment: Guys fixed the proof. Now it works completely.

Comment: @Balajisb Thank you for the explanation. But I do not think we need anything other than the techniques that is available in any acceptable basic algebraic number theory books to answer this question. At least this is my impression after solving tons of problems from the book where this problem is from.